# Creating a permutation matix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm writing a function that returns a permutation matrix. Inside, it does something like this

```
PermutationMatrix<Dynamic> my_favourite_permutation () {
    Eigen::Matrix<uint, Dynamic, 1> x {4, 3, 1, 2, 0};
    PermutationWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<uint, Dynamic, 1>> p
        = PermutationWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<uint, Dynamic, 1>> (x);
    return p;
}
```

The use case includes something like

```
auto p = my_favourite_permutation();
cout << p.toDenseMatrix() << endl;
```

Unfortunately the code above gets caught in a static assertion:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:32: error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
     #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
```

Interestingly if instead of `return p;` I do `return p.inverse();` then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Eigen, but it seems that `PermutationMatrix` defaults to some other type of indices than `uint`. If you want to use `uint`, you have to specify it in the template parameter of the return type:

```cpp
PermutationMatrix<Dynamic, Dynamic, uint> my_favourite_permutation() {
    ...
}
```